# JWPlayer: aspectratio not working with numeric width

Tags: jwplayer

According to the [documentation](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference), when `aspectratio` is set, the `height` is ignored, so I do

```
jwplayer("videoEx").setup({
    "file": "myvideourl",
    "image":"/images/slideshowbg.png",
    "width":640,
    "aspectratio":"16:9"
});
```

But it doesn't work properly, the video container's size will be 640*270(I guess 270 is a default height), while the video player's size being 480*270, making two black bars on the sides of the video player.

I have to do

```
jwplayer("videoEx").setup({
    "file": "myvideourl",
    "image":"/images/slideshowbg.png",
    "width":"53%",
    "aspectratio":"16:9"
});
```

to get a proper video player where the container is same size.

Is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is intended.

From the docs:

aspectratio String
Maintains proportions when width is a percentage. Will not be used if the player is a static size. 
Note: Must be entered in ratio "x:y" format